# File Upload progress bar with custom file upload

Tags: custom-options, file-upload

We need to show the progress bar uploading image for product custom option frontend. And also show the preview the uploaded file. Is it possible to apply admin section file uploader.

Comment: admin section file uploader means ? you want flash file uploader on front side ?

Comment: yes. i want admin section image file uploader

Comment: you can not use admin section at fronend but you can grab files and functionality at front side and customizer as per your needs.

Comment: OK. Is there any module for custom file upload? If yes, please share the links.

Comment: Check this plugin - https://www.micosolutions.com/upload-ultimate-for-magento

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. Is there any free plugin?